# How would I add array inside square bracket []

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array which returns values like this

`let arr = {Routing Category: 'new', TimeSlice: 'AM', Destination1: 'test', Value1: '701', Destination2: 'Test'}`

but I want to wrap this array inside [] bracket like this

`[{Routing Category: 'new', TimeSlice: 'AM', Destination1: 'test', Value1: '701', Destination2: 'Test'}]`

How would I do that. Please help

I was pushing this array into new array but that was returning as object object.

Comment: arr is **not** an array, but rather a dictionary of key-value pairs. What is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

The `arr` variable which you are referring to as an array is in fact an `object` and not an array.

But you can achieve what you want like this.

```
const newArr = [arr]
```

Try taking a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) to learn about objects in JavaScript.

Comment: @Naina Happy to hear I was helpful.  You can accept the answer as correct to make it clear this question is answered correctly.